# mount external drive in read-only system

Tags: mount

Last night my wife's laptop running OpenSUSE appears to have had some sort of failure such that on start-up it gives a whole bunch of errors and ends up prompting for a root password to start up with read-only access to a shell.

In this read-only mode I was able to view that all of the important files appear to still be there so I want to back them up before doing anything.

I attached an external USB drive and it comes up with a message:

```
usb 4-3: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
usb 4-3: new device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2338
sub 4-3: new device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[...etc....]
scsi3 : SCSU emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access WDS WD25 WD-[...more hard drive info...etc.]
[...etc...]
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
 sdb: [mac] sdb1 sdb2 sdb3 sdb4
sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
```

So I assume all that means is that it found the drive.

Now, I want to mount it to be able to copy files to it.

Two questions?

1. How do I find it i /dev/
2. Even if I find it, how do I mount it when I only have read-only access?

Thanks for any help here.

Comment: OK - I just ran mount -n -o remount,rw / and now appear to be in read-write mode.  Still could use help mounting the external drive though.

Comment: Can we get the output if `fdisk -l`? But if I have to gues I'd say `mkdir /mnt/tmp && mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/tmp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can even remount the file system by force remount - just remember you need to fsck the system. if the system mount it as read only there must be something wrong with the filesystem.

```
mount -n -o remount /
```

for the usb stick, usually it is emulated as scsi, 
you can use

```
fdisk -l
```

to list all the connected drives at the moment.
for mounting e.g. a ntfs drive, on /dev/sdb1, try:

```
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

substitute `vfat` if you are using fat16/32.

Comment: Alright.  fdisk -l gives me: "Disk /dev/dd: 250.0 GB .... Disk /dev/sdc doesn't contain a valid partition table"   I tried mounting with the above command and that did not work.  I have tried several things and at one point, I did manage to get it to mount read-only, but since I'm trying to write to it that was not what I'm trying to do.  What do you think the next best option is?  I could try a regular usb stick.  Do you think it will make a difference?

Comment: i think you want to post the whole fdisk output in your original question. if you want to copy things out i think you can try to get the harddisk out and use explore2fs/mount it in other box.

Comment: Ah - I got it read-only again using "mount /dev/sdc3 /mnt/" (by process of elimination).  It gives me "hfs: write access to a jounaled filesystem is not supported, use the force option at your own risk, mounting read-only." (I'm guessing jounaled is "journaled")  So this probably means better to go with a USB stick that I can easily reformat.  There's stuff on this external drive that I don't want to lose.

Comment: you are correct

Comment: worked with the usb stick - thanks for telling me about fdisk -l.  I have everything backed up (using cp -a and also made a .tar.gz just in case...).  Now ready to wipe the drive.  Do you have any recommendations about fixing the drive or will a clean install of Ubuntu where I let it format the drive fix things through reformating?

Comment: i think what you want is a complete wipe of the harddrive PLUS examining whether the harddrive had hardware level faults. faulty harddrive belongs to the rubbish bin (or risk your data). tools such as smartmontools will help to read the SMART status. Ask a new question to get new answerers to your question instead of chatting here :)